# error as "ORA:00900:Invalid SQL Statement,Vendor code 900" ,

Tags: sql, debugging, compiler-errors, sqlplus

Trying to Debug one proc in SQL developer and getting  error as "ORA:00900:Invalid SQL Statement,Vendor code 900" ,
if anyone has faced this error before please suggest what could be issue and how we can fix it ?

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and put the query in the question *as text*.  If you can simplify the query, then that is helpful -- a minimum reproducible example is best.

Comment: Enter a valid SQL statement?

Comment: You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.